# Total count of Previously and current selected images in multiple image upload in php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am creating form , in which i want user upload its multiple images through upload button. My issue is,
Suppose user  select 2 images at first time ,now he want to add 3 more images 
when its again upload 3 images it shows image count 3 .I want that the image count should be 5 (Total images at first time upload and second time upload).
How will it work.

My code is:

```
    <input type="file" id="files" name="dog_img[]" class="upload-img" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple>
    <input type="hidden" name="img-count"  id="img-count" value="0">
```

jQUERY :

```
$('#files').change(function () {
    var co = 0;
    var len = 5;
    var preimgcount = $("#img-count").val();
    if (preimgcount != 0) {
        console.log('preimgcount - ' + preimgcount);
        co = parseInt(preimgcount);
        len = parseInt(len) - preimgcount;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var num_of_images =  $("#files")[0].files.length;
        $("#img-count").attr('value' , num_of_images);
        (function (j, self) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = e.target.result;
                image.onload = function () {
                    var height = this.height;
                    var width = this.width;
                    if (height < 700 || width < 1000) {
                        alert("Height and Width must not exceed 1024px.");
                        return false;
                    }
                };
                co++;
                console.log('co - ' + co);
                $('.gallery-row').append('<div class="col-md-2" id="pip"><span id="' + [co] + '" data-id="' + [co] + '" class="click-form"><img class="imageThumb" src="' + e.target.result + '"/>' + '</span><span data-id="' + [co] + '" class="remove">X</span></div>');
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(self.files[j])
        })(i, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your limit of images 5?

Comment: yes limit of images is 5 – varsha just now   edit

Comment: I checked your code and it works properly. What is your problem exaclty? Do you mean the mumber of images displayed next to files button?

Comment: When user select first time 2 images then the value in the hidden filed is 2...but if user want to add 3 more images  then the value of hidden filed should be updated to 5 not 3.

Comment: You were right, it did not work properly. Check my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You have got some minor mistakes in your code, but it works properly, the `co` variable has the proper value.

**Here is working example**

```js
$('#files').change(function() {
  var co = 0;
  var len = 5;
  var img_count = $("#img-count");
  var preimgcount = img_count.val();
  if (preimgcount != 0) {
    console.log('preimgcount - ' + preimgcount);
    co = parseInt(preimgcount);
    len = parseInt(len) - preimgcount;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var num_of_images = $("#files")[0].files.length;
    (function(j, self) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = e.target.result;
        image.onload = function() {
          var height = this.height;
          var width = this.width;
          if (height < 700 || width < 1000) {
            alert("Height and Width must not exceed 1024px.");
            return false;
          }
        };
        co++;
        img_count.val(co);
        console.log('co - ' + co);
        $('.gallery-row').append('<div class="col-md-2" id="pip"><span id="' + [co] + '" data-id="' + [co] + '" class="click-form"><img class="imageThumb" src="' + e.target.result + '"/>' + '</span><span data-id="' + [co] + '" class="remove">X</span></div>');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(self.files[j])
    })(i, this);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="dog_img[]" class="upload-img" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple>
<input type="hidden" name="img-count" id="img-count" value="0">
```

Comment: .....thanks for the reply ..but by using your solution ...images are not adding in the second time

Comment: the count of images near upload button  is not showing total count of images ....if i click on browse image it updated the images that i selected at first time

Comment: Yes, that is a default behavior of upload button. You can not change it. What you can do is hide that button, and make your own and event on click to trigger cilcik on upload button.